# Can spark manage partitions larger than the executor size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Question:

Spark seems to be able to manage partitions that are bigger than the executor size. How does it do that?

What I have tried so far:

1. I picked up a [CSV](https://data.cdc.gov/Case-Surveillance/COVID-19-Case-Surveillance-Public-Use-Data-with-Ge/ynhu-f2s2) with: Size on disk - 12.3 GB, Size in memory deserialized - 3.6 GB, Size in memory serialized - 1964.9 MB. I got these sizes from caching the data in memory deserialized and serialized both and 12.3 GB is the size of the file on the disk.
2. To check if spark can handle partitions larger than the executor size, I created a cluster with just one executor with `spark.executor.memory` equal to 500mb. Also, I set executor cores (`spark.executor.cores`) to 2 and, increased `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` to 13 GB. I also switched off Dynamic allocation and adaptive for good measure. The entire session configuration is:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.\
config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled",False).\
config("spark.executor.cores","2").\
config("spark.executor.instances","1").\
config("spark.executor.memory","500m").\
config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", False).\
config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes","13g").\
getOrCreate()
```

3. I read the CSV and checked the number of partitions that it is being read in by `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`. Output = 2. This would be confirmed later on as well in the number of tasks
4. Then I run `df.persist(storagelevel.StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY); df.count()`

Following are the observations I made:

1. No caching happens till the data for one batch of tasks (equal to number of cpu cores in case you have set 1 cpu core per task) is read in completely. I conclude this since there is no entry that shows up in the storage tab of the web UI.
2. Each partition here ends up being around 6 GB on disk. Which should, at a minimum, be around 1964.9 MB/2 (=Size in memory serializez/2) in memory. Which is around 880 MB. There is no spill. Below is the relevant snapshot of the web UI from when around 11 GB of the data has been read in. You can see that Input has been almost 11GB and at this time there was nothing in the storage tab.
   [image]

**Questions**:

1. Since the memory per executor is 300 MB (Execution + Storage) + 200 MB (User memory). How is spark able to manage ~880 MB partitions that too 2 of them in parallel (one by each core)?
2. The data read in does not show up in the Storage, is not (and, can not be) in the executor and, there is no spill as well. where exactly is that read in data?

Attaching a SS of the web UI post that job completion in case that might be useful
[image]

Attaching a SS of the Executors tab in case that might be useful:
[image]

Comment: Can you share "Jobs", "Stages" pages too?